# Adhara Socket doesn't work on iOS Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, socket.io, cocoapods

I want to achieve real-time Socket.IO in Flutter.
i have downloaded the Adhara Socket Package and it doesn't work on iOS, makes my build failed in both Android Studio & xCode.
library link: https://pub.dev/packages/adhara_socket_io

and here's my pubsec.yaml file:

```
   version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  #Checkboxes Library
  grouped_buttons: ^1.0.4

  #Google Maps Library.
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.28+1

  #Flutter Map Picker
  google_map_location_picker: ^3.3.3

  #Flutter GeoLocator
  geolocator: 5.3.2+2

  #Flutter Permissions
  permission: ^0.1.7

  #Flutter Lottie Animations
  lottie: ^0.5.1

  #Flutter Inner Navigation Drawer
  flutter_inner_drawer: ^0.5.6+1

  #Flutter Native Navigation Drawer
  drawerbehavior: ^1.0.3

  #Flutter Numeric Keyboard
  numeric_keyboard: ^1.0.0

  #Flutter Curved Navigation Drawer
  curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.3



  #Flutter BLOC
  flutter_bloc: ^6.0.1

  #Flutter EQUATABLE
  equatable: ^1.0.2

  #Flutter DIO
  dio: ^3.0.9

  #Json Serialization
  json_annotation: ^3.0.1

  #Flutter Validator
  validators: ^2.0.0+1

  #Flutter SharedPrefs
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.8

  #Flutter Poly Lines
  flutter_polyline_points: ^0.2.2

  #FLutter Location Library
  location: ^2.3.5

  #Flutter Map PolyLine
  google_map_polyline:

  #Flutter Google Fonts
  google_fonts: ^1.1.0


  #Flutter Progress Dialog
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.4

  #Flutter Toast
  toast: ^0.1.5

  #rxDart
  rxdart: ^0.24.1

  #GET NAVIGATOR
  get: ^3.5.1

  #FLUTTER OFFLINE
  flutter_offline: "^0.3.0"

  #FLUTTER WEB SOCKET
  adhara_socket_io: ^0.4.2+1


  dev_dependencies:
    flutter_test:
      sdk: flutter
```

and here's my package implementation:

```
try{
  SocketIOManager manager = SocketIOManager();
  SocketIO socket = await manager.createInstance(SocketOptions('http://192.168.8.187:3000',nameSpace: '/',enableLogging: true,path: null));       //TODO change the port  accordingly
  socket.onConnect((data){
    print("connected...");

  });
  // socket.on('test-channel:Socket', (data){   //sample event
  //   print("accessed channel");
  // });

  socket.connect();
  socket.on('Driver.${9}:new_order', (data) {print("fuck");});


  }
  catch(e){

      print(e.toString());

  }
```

Flutter doctor output:

```
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.2, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021, locale en)
    • Flutter version 1.20.2 at /Users/mackbookpro/Downloads/flutter
    • Framework revision bbfbf1770c (3 weeks ago), 2020-08-13 08:33:09 -0700
    • Engine revision 9d5b21729f
    • Dart version 2.9.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/mackbookpro/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.4.1, Build version 11E503a
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 48.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.1.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[!] VS Code (version 1.48.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • HD1901 (mobile)                     • b255e813                             • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)
    • iPhone SE (2nd generation) (mobile) • 5402105E-CC55-4173-9598-64DEF04BB3B5 • ios           • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-4 (simulator)
```

build log:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:

    ↳
    /Users/mackbookpro/Desktop/Tiger Taxi/new_tiger_driver/ios/Pods/Starscream/Sources/Starscream/Compression.swift:59:25: warning: 'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead
            return try data.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes:UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Data in
                            ^
    /Users/mackbookpro/Desktop/Tiger Taxi/new_tiger_driver/ios/Pods/Starscream/Sources/Starscream/Compression.swift:83:29: warning: initialization of 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>' results in a dangling pointer
                strm.next_out = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(&buffer)
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/mackbookpro/Desktop/Tiger Taxi/new_tiger_driver/ios/Pods/Starscream/Sources/Starscream/Compression.swift:83:57: note: implicit argument conversion from '[UInt8]' to 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>' produces a pointer valid only for the duration of the call to 'init(_:)'
                strm.next_out = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(&buffer)
                                                            ^~~~~~~
    /Users/mackbookpro/Desktop/Tiger Taxi/new_tiger_driver/ios/Pods/Starscream/Sources/Starscream/Compression.swift:83:57: note: use the 'withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer' method on Array in order to explicitly convert argument to buffer pointer valid for a defined scope
                strm.next_out = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(&buffer)
                                                            ^
    /Users/mackbookpro/Desktop/Tiger Taxi/new_tiger_driver/ios/Pods/Starscream/Sources/Starscream/Compression.swift:145:33: warning: initialization of 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>' results in a dangling pointer
                    strm.next_out = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(&buffer)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/mackbookpro/Desktop/Tiger Taxi/new_tiger_driver/ios/Pods/Starscream/Sources/Starscream/Compression.swift:145:61: note: implicit argument conversion from '[UInt8]' to 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>' produces a pointer valid only for the duration of the call to 'init(_:)'
                    strm.next_out = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(&buffer)
                                                                ^~~~~~~
    /Users/mackbookpro/Desktop/Tiger Taxi/new_tiger_driver/ios/Pods/Starscream/Sources/Starscream/Compression.swift:145:61: note: use the 'withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer' method on Array in order to explicitly convert argument to buffer pointer valid for a defined scope
                    strm.next_out = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(&buffer)
                                                                ^
    /Users/mackbookpro/Desktop/Tiger Taxi/new_tiger_driver/ios/Pods/Starscream/Sources/Starscream/Compression.swift:140:14: warning: 'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead
            data.withUnsafeBytes { (ptr:UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Void in
                 ^
    /Users/mackbookpro/Desktop/Tiger Taxi/new_tiger_driver/ios/Pods/Starscream/Sources/Starscream/WebSocket.swift:282:30: warning: 'withUnsafeMutableBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeMutableBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead
                let _ = peerName.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (peerNamePtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>) in
                                 ^
    /Users/mackbookpro/Desktop/Tiger Taxi/new_tiger_driver/ios/Pods/Starscream/Sources/Starscream/WebSocket.swift:1326:14: warning: 'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead
            data.withUnsafeBytes { _ = CC_SHA1($0, CC_LONG(data.count), &digest) }
                 ^
    /Users/mackbookpro/Desktop/Tiger Taxi/new_tiger_driver/ios/Pods/Starscream/Sources/Starscream/WebSocket.swift:1327:16: warning: 'init(bytes:)' is deprecated: use `init(_:)` instead
            return Data(bytes: digest).base64EncodedString()
                   ^
    /Users/mackbookpro/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/adhara_socket_io-0.4.2+1/ios/Classes/AdharaSocket.swift:85:38: warning: expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to 'Any'
                                "reqId": reqId
                                         ^~~~~
    /Users/mackbookpro/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/adhara_socket_io-0.4.2+1/ios/Classes/AdharaSocket.swift:85:38: note: provide a default value to avoid this warning
                                "reqId": reqId
                                         ^~~~~
                                               ?? <#default value#>
    /Users/mackbookpro/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/adhara_socket_io-0.4.2+1/ios/Classes/AdharaSocket.swift:85:38: note: force-unwrap the value to avoid this warning
                                "reqId": reqId
                                         ^~~~~
                                              !
    /Users/mackbookpro/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/adhara_socket_io-0.4.2+1/ios/Classes/AdharaSocket.swift:85:38: note: explicitly cast to 'Any' with 'as Any' to silence this warning
                                "reqId": reqId
                                         ^~~~~
                                               as Any
    /Users/mackbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-eubpodhclpglohfjgqiizvunrhxh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-8260F2EAAE9F274664AABFD4.sh: line 2: /Users/mackbookpro/Desktop/Tiger Taxi/new_tiger_driver/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh: Permission denied
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
```

any hopes for fixing this :'(

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Comment: yes, i fixed it.

Comment: Please close this question or answer it below.

Comment: how you've fixed can you tell me

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by setting the namespace parameter to "/" instead of null, because in the swift library it's not nullable, that what caused the issue for me.
happy coding community!